# PHP file_get_contents behavior across versions and operating systems

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp, windows-10

I am using `file_get_contents` in PHP to get information from a client's collections on contentDM. CDM has an API so you can get that info by making php queries, like, say:

http://servername:port/webutilities/index.php?q=function/arguments

It has worked pretty well thus far, across computers and operating systems. However, this time things work a little differently.

http://servername/utils/collection/mycollectionname/id/myid/filename/myname

For this query I fill in mycollection, myid, and myname with relevant values. myid and mycollection have to exist in the system, obviously. However, myname can be anything you want. When you run the query, it doesn't return a web page or anything to your browser. It just automatically downloads a file with myname as the name of the file, and puts it in your local /Downloads folder.

I DON'T WISH TO DOWNLOAD THIS FILE. I just want to read the contents of the file it returns directly into PHP as a string. The file I am trying to get just contains xml data.

`file_get_contents` works to get the data in that file, if I use it with PHP7 and Apache on my laptop running Ubuntu. But, on my desktop which runs Windows 10, and XAMPP (Apache and PHP5), I get this error (I've replaced sensitive data with ###):

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(###/utils/collection/###/id/1110/filename/1111.cpd):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\Titus\Documents\GitHub\NativeAmericanSCArchive\NASCA-site\api\update.php
>   on line 18

My coworkers have been unable to help me so I am curious if anyone here can confirm or deny whether this is an operating system issue, or a PHP version issue, and whether there's a solid alternative method that is likely to work in PHP5 and on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: PHP5, which version exactly?

Comment: Version 5.6.30.

Comment: it is not an http wrapper warning. http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-wrappers.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_get_contents() is a simple screwdriver. It's very good for getting data by simply `GET` requests where the header, HTTP request method, timeout, cookiejar, redirects, and other important things do not matter.

fopen() with a stream context or cURL with setopt are powerdrills with every bit and option you can think of.

In addition to this, due to some recent website hacks, we had to secure our sites more. In doing so, we discovered that file_get_contents failed to work, where curl still would work.

Not 100%, but I believe that this php.ini setting may have been blocking the file_get_contents request.

```
; Disable allow_url_fopen for security reasons
allow_url_fopen = 0
```

Either way, our code now works with curl.

**reference :**
http://25labs.com/alternative-for-file_get_contents-using-curl/
http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_fopen.html

So, You can solve this problem by using PHP cURL extension. Here is an example that does the same thing you were trying:

```
function curl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }
$url = 'your_api_url';
$data = curl($url);
```

And finally you can check your data by print_r($data). Hope it you it will works and you will understand.

**Reference** : http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: This works! Are you aware what is the limiting factor that is making file_get_contents work on my laptop but not on my desktop? I assume it would be the PHP version but I can't be sure.

Comment: I think there is no limitation. But I think the best way to call api in php using `curl`. I got this problem before and I used to `curl` as the best solution. Glad to know that my answer is helpful for you. So select my solution as your answer.

Comment: I'd be happy to, but my question hasn't been quite answered yet. cURL is a solid alternative method that seems to work for me on my Ubuntu/PHP7 machine as well as my Windows/PHP5 machine. But a large portion of my question was to understand what went wrong. The file_get_contents function will work on Ubuntu/PHP7 but not for the same application on Windows/PHP5. Clearly there is at least one limiting factor between machines. If you can't answer that, could you describe in brief what it is about cURL that makes it better than file_get_contents? That'll give me some context to the issue at least.

Comment: @MatthewJendrasiak I updated my answer. Please look at this. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Sumon :) That clears things up a bit. Marked it as the answer.